# como realizar calculos de porcentaje en c#

Tags: c#

Necesito una linea de codigo que quiero utilzar en el evento keypress de un textbox.

Tiene que hacer que cuando el usuario presione <kbd>enter</kbd> realice:

```
txtcompra * txtganancia (%)+ txtcompra
txtventa.tostring();
```

el calculo seria algo asi para mas claridad:

```
precio de venta= precio de compra + (precio de compra * %de ganancia)
```

Código actual:

```
database.SoloNumeros(e);
if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
{
      float pventa, pcompra, ganancia;
      pcompra = float.Parse(txtcompra.Text);
      ganancia = float.Parse(txtganancia.Text);

      pventa = pcompra + pcompra * ganancia;
      txtventa.Text = pventa.ToString();
}
```

> error: input string was not in the correct format

Comment: hola, y cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola Samuel, por favor comparte el código que has intentado hasta el momento y donde está el error.

Comment: database.SoloNumeros(e);
            if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
            {
                float pventa, pcompra, ganancia;
                pcompra = float.Parse(txtcompra.Text);
                ganancia = float.Parse(txtganancia.Text);

                pventa = pcompra + pcompra * ganancia;
                txtventa.Text = pventa.ToString();

error: input string was not in the correct format

Comment: Samuel no lo pongas como comentario.Pulsa en [Edit] tu pregunta y añade el código

Comment: perdon no se utilizar muy bien esto lo pongo con espacios y los pone pegados

Comment: en cual de todas las lineas?? y apuesto que tienes problemas al transformar numeros con . o , como separador decimal..

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si te está dando ese error, el problema está en tus datos de entrada `txtcompra.Text` y `txtganancia.Text`. Probablemente,por usar un punto como separador de decimales o al revés

Comment: no se si entendi bien pero quizas deberia de cambiar el maskedtextbox 0.00% por un 0,00%?

Comment: Samuel mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Tras leer tus comentarios, parece que tienes varios problemas en tu código.

Por un lado, en tu `TextBox` `ganancia` tienes al parecer un símbolo `%`. Con ese simbolo no vas a poder convertir el texto a `float`,asi que debes eliminarlo al pasarlo a la función `Parse`.

Por otro, si la Cultura configurada en tu sistema es Español, no te va a reconocer el punto como separador decimal (ya que en español el separador decimal es la `,`,el punto se usa como separador de miles), asi que utiliza `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` para que el punto sea considerado separador decimal. Asi que debería quedar asi esa linea:

```
ganancia = float.Parse(txtganancia.Text
                     .Replace("%", ""), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

También es interesante usar `TryParse` en lugar de `Parse`, de tal manera que no recibas una excepción si no es posible convertir el texto.

Por ultimo, cuando se trata de trabajar con moneda, el tipo adecuado no es nunca `float`, sino `decimal`. Si no lo usas, puedes tener varios problemas asociados a la matemática de coma flotante.

Con todos estos cambios, tu código debería quedar asi mas o menos:

```
database.SoloNumeros(e);
if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
{
     decimal pventa, pcompra, ganancia;

     if (!decimal.TryParse(txtcompra.Text,
                           System.Globalization.NumberStyles.None, 
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           out pcompra))
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error al convertir Precio de compra a decimal");
     }
     else
     {
         if (!decimal.TryParse(txtganancia.Text
                          .Replace("%", ""), 
                          System.Globalization.NumberStyles.None, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          out ganancia))
         {
              MessageBox.Show("Error al convertir Porcentaje de ganancia a decimal");
         }
         else
         {
              pventa = pcompra * (1 +(ganancia/100));
              txtventa.Text = pventa.ToString();
         }
      }

}
```

Comment: igual las cuentas estan mal.. si ganancia es un porcentaje, por ejemplo 10, deberia sumarse un 10% a compra, y con esa forma de hacer las cuentas no lo hace.. la confusion reside que OP pone el signo %, pero al hacer las cuentas nadie tuvo en cuenta que 3% es en realidad 0,03...

Comment: gracias @Pikoh me funciono todo bien . una pregunta cuando me pasa el string al textbox de venta despues del calculo me lo pasa asi: 1100.0 eso esta bien?

Comment: Eso es como lo convierte por defecto a string decimal, pero puedes modificarlo con el formato que tu quieras

Comment: Podrias usar por ejemplo `pventa.ToString("#0.#");` que te muestra los decimales solo si existen

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que ya tengas el evento `onKeyDown` hecho (de no ser así debería ser lo primero que hagas), tienes que comprobar que la tecla que pulses sea el Enter:

```
    private void nombreCampo_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {


      double venta= double.Parse(txtcompra.Text) * (double.Parse(txtganancia.Text)/100)+ double.Parse(txtcompra.Text);

    txtventa.Text=venta.ToString();
    }

}
```

Yo lo he hecho con `double`, pero puedes hacer con `float` perfectamente.

---

Para evitar el error de conversión que te aparece puedes utilizar la función `float.TryParse` que hace que, si el valor que has insertado no se puede formatear, no lo formatea:

```
double compra=0;
double ganancia=0;
double.TryParse(txtcompra.Text, out compra);
double.TryParse(txtganancia.Text, out ganancia);
double venta= compra * (ganancia/100)+ compra;
```

Comment: me da este error> input string was not in the correct format

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor El error quiere decir que el valor que intentas formatear, en este caso a float, no es correcto, comprueba que los valores que insertas en el campo de texto son números

Comment: si, hermano mira los datos que estoy ingresando a modo de prueba  son:

Comment: txtcompra = 1000
txtganancia= 0.10
txtventa= calculo

Comment: he editado la respuesta mira @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor

Comment: lo use me corrio pero no me realiza los calculos me doy a entender:
del maskedtextbox elimine el punto osea ahora es 00%
use estos datos a modo de prueba:

compra= 1000
ganancia= 10
venta me dio como resultado 1000

osea no me calculo

Comment: he editado la respuesta mira @ErlantzCalvo

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres controlar son errores por formatos incorrectos el código quedaría así:

```
  private void txtventa_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {
            float pventa, pcompra, ganancia;
            var s = txtcompra.Text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (!float.TryParse(txtcompra.Text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), out pcompra))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Formato erroneo en TxtCompra");
                return;
            }
            if (!float.TryParse(txtganancia.Text.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), out ganancia))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Formato erroneo en txtganancia");
                return;
            }


            pventa = pcompra + pcompra * ganancia;
            txtventa.Text = pventa.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

Uso el `InvariantCulture` para que, sea cual sea la configuración regional, se espere el `.` como separador decimal.

Un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias hermano me funciono, solo una duda tengo un maskedtextbox de formato 00% cuando quite el signo de porciento me funciono tienes alguna idea de como hacerle para poder usar el signo  sin que me de error

Comment: @SamuelIgnacioSusanaConfesor hace 20 minutos que te di la solucion a lo del simbolo de porcentaje :)

Comment: no lo habia visto @Pikoh voy  a probarlo

Comment: Como bien dice @Pikoh en su respuesta te dice como solucionar lo del % que cuando he acabado de poner mi respuesta he visto la suya y es valida.

Answer (score -1):

Seria algo así como:

```
        float pventa, pcompra, ganancia;
        pcompra = float.Parse(txtcompra.Text);
        ganancia = float.Parse(txtganancia.Text);

        pventa = pcompra + pcompra * ganancia / 100;
        txtventa.Text = pventa.ToString();
```

Faltaría agregar las validaciones del parse a float. Eso queda de tarea.

Comment: hermano, disculpa la moletia pero no soy muy bueno con las conversiones. si me pudieras ayudar completo de verdad te lo agradeceria

Comment: utilize tu codigo y me dice: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Que valor estas ingresando en los text boxes txtcompra y txtganancia?

Comment: compra en la base de datos es [money]  y el ganancia es porcentaje y utilizo un maskedtextbox y solo uso numeros en ellos @Urrestarazu.Ale

Comment: Yo te recomendaría poner puntos de interrupción en la linea para ver que valores te estan intentando convertir.
Esta es la documentación para convertir un string en float:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb(v=vs.110).aspx